# findByIdAndUpdate e findByIdAndRemove retornando erro ao consultar ID inválido

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Estou utilizando Mongoose e ExpressJS em uma pequena aplicação que tenho, tudo funciona bem até um ID inexistente ser utilizado para deletar ou atualizar um registro.

Meu problema está nos métodos:

- findByIdAndUpdate
- findByIdAndRemove

Quando um ID "inexistente" é passado acabo recebendo uma exception do tipo:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "61589e1e992435729ef4921d1" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"
```

> citei "inexistente" entre aspas pois se o ID informado for válido (ObjectID) e não existir no banco, a exception não é gerada.

Seria possível ainda sim utilizar os métodos listados acima, porém, ter um null ou algo assim como retorno?

Meu controller está mais ou menos assim:

```
const UserModel = require('../../database/models/user');

module.exports = {
    index: async (_, res) => {
        const result = await UserModel.find({});

        return res.json(result);
    },
    create: async (req, res) => {
        const user = new UserModel(req.body);
        
        const result = await user.save();

        return res.json(result).status(201);
    },
    update: async (req, res) => {
        const result = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, { new: true });

        return res.status(200).json(result);
    },
    destroy: async (req, res) => {
        const result = await UserModel.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);

        if (!result) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Nenhum registro encontrado!',
                data: {
                    id: req.params.id,
                },
            });
        }

        return res.status(204).json();
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema verificando o valor da variável `result`.

Caso ela seja null o correto seria retonar o valor 404, esta lógica pode ser aplicada da seguinte forma:

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
exports.updateUserbyId = (req, res) => {
    const options = { returnOriginal: false };
    db.get().collection('user').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, {$set: {"name": req.body.name }}, options).then((result) => {
        if (result.value === null) {
            return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
        }
        res.status(200).json(result.value);
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({errors: [{location: "users", msg: err, param: req.params.id}]})
    })
}
```

Caso esteja estranhando a sintaxe o motivo é que eu não uso o `mongoose`, eu faço as consultas utilizando a lib do `mongodb`.

Então existem algumas diferenças:

Esta minha variável `options` informa que (caso encontrado) eu desejo que o retorno seja meu `documento` após fazer o update com os novos dados.

Ao fazer a consulta eu faço a conversão para `ObjectId` (o mongoose já faz isso, então para o seu caso não vai ser necessário).

outra coisa é que eu uso o modelo de callback mas a lógica pode ser utilizada em sua rota de `findByIdAndUpdate` e `findByIdAndRemove`.

Ao fazer o update no meu objeto eu passo explicitamente os atributos que eu desejo atualizar do meu `model`, você vê pelo parâmetro `$set` da função `findOneAndUpdate`.

A lógica utilizada aqui é a maneira recomendada pela lib [`mongodb`](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve/).